# Bash script which replaces constants makes two files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script which replaces a set of constants in the html, js and css files in a directory.

It works fine but for some reason it creates an additional file with a suffix of "-e" on the file type.

For example, "index.html" would become "index.html-e". It also creates a file called "index.html". Both files appear identical.

The offending line of code for the html is:

```
 find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i -e "s/#$KEY/$VALUE/g" {} \;
```

where $KEY and $VALUE are both simply strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I came to was to just remove the backups created (helpfully pointed out by @choroba). Done like so:

```
find . -name "*.html-e" -type f|xargs rm -f
find . -name "*.js-e" -type f|xargs rm -f
find . -name "*.css-e" -type f|xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score 2):

Some implementations of `sed` require a backup extension after `-i`. The created file is therefore the original file before the replacement. You might specify a more common backup extension, i.e. `~`:

```
sed -i~ -e "..."
```

BTW, to verify whether the two files are identical, try

```
diff index.html index.html-e
```

Comment: `diff -qs` is a better "do these files differ" test when you don't care about the differences at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description of the result I suspect the command you ran was not:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i -e "s/#$KEY/$VALUE/g" {} \;
```

but rather

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i-e "s/#$KEY/$VALUE/g" {} \;
```

which passes the `-e` as extension to `-i` and then uses the script as default argument.

Oh, or what @choroba said if that space actually was there (I am not aware of `sed` implementations that work that way but that would certainly explain the behaviour you are seeing without assuming a transcription error to your question here).

Comment: Nope I'm afraid there is indeed a space between -i and -e

Comment: @Ger Yeah, choroba comments on that in his answer. I was not aware of implementations like that.